# Feeds: update nodes using a second import

Tags: feeds

Is there a way in which you can use a second feeds import, to update nodes created during a first import?

In my first import, I create nodes and save a custom ID (from old system), and I want to reuse that custom ID in the second import to update the existing nodes and add a taxonomy value.

1. First importer:

[image]

2. Second importer:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update existing content using feeds importer, you will have to mark **Customer ID** field as a ***Unique Key***.

Comment: Where can you set that? I only see the option to put it as **Unique Key**

Comment: and do you need to do this in both importers or only in the 2nd one?

Comment: Yes you are right, thats Unique Key.

Comment: That doesn't work, it keeps on creating new nodes, instead of updating the existing ones based in the Custom ID

Comment: Have you selected Update existing content in module configuration?

Comment: Yes, I also tried with Replace but that has the same effect

Comment: Please share field mapping and configuration screenshot into your question.

Comment: Uploaded images..

Comment: In 2nd import, select zaal_id(field_zaal_id) as target instead of GUID.

Comment: You mean temporary target? http://cl.ly/image/2S0Z2O3V2e25?_ga=1.260744271.392578222.1446191095

Comment: Yeah right!!! :)

Comment: Temporary target doens't work, it does work when I add the field_zaal_id as target! Many thanks!